# R : passing a variable to parameter "pattern" in "gsub" function

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub, sapply

I want to use the function gsub with sapply on a dataframe:

```
df_mod=as.data.frame(sapply(data_mod,gsub,pattern=data_mod$marq,replacement=""))
```

my problem is in the parameter `pattern` on the gsub function. In all the examples that I've seen, they pass a string to this parameter, like: `pattern="string"`. For my case, I want to pass a variable as mentioned above : `pattern=data_mod$marq`

But I keep having these warnings that affected my results:

```
  Warning messages:
  1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
  2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
  3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is it possible to pass a variable to `pattern` parameter. If so, It will give me a perfect result.

Please help me.

**UPDATE**

switching `sapply` by `mapply` resolved the problem :

```
df_mod=as.data.frame(mapply(gsub,data_mod$marq,"",data_mod$nom_det))
```

Comment: @nrussell, Thank you : switching sapply by mapply rsolved my problem.

Comment: @David Arenburg, Thank you : switching sapply by mapply rsolved my problem.